# Are the random variables in the figure independent?

Tags: dataset, statistics

[image]

I have this plot of 2 random variables (Assume X and Y) . A point represents a value of Y for a given value of X. I think these variables cannot be considered independent. Here is my reasoning.

Consider the values Y takes for X = 0. For X = 0, Y can take a wide range of values (-4 to 8). Now consider the values that Y takes for X = 8. (Only Y = 0). Since the distribution of Y depends on the value of X these variables cannot be considered independent. Is my reasoning correct ?

Comment: I would suggest to see coorelation between these variables. Looking at the scatter plot it seems they have low correlation. Not Sure, in what terms independence is being discusses in your question?

Comment: Zero correlation does not always mean random variables are independent. Correlation usually refers to Pearson correlation which detects if there is any linear relationship amongst variables. The correlation of these random variables is low, but the distribution of Y does not seem to be independent of X as I explained in the question.

Comment: Agreed, just looking at 1 values X=8 (Y=0) does not imply a dependence. As in the middle where you have most of your values i.e Y [-2,2] X varies from [-4,8]. So its seems independent to me.

Comment: Yeah. I asked the question for this specific reason. So can I consider these random variables independent?

Answer (score 1):

In probability theory independence between variables A and B is defined as:

$$p(A)\times p(B)=p(A,B)$$

This is equivalent to $p(A|B)=p(A)$ or also $p(B|A)=p(B)$. This means that events A and B are independent iff *the chances that one happens are not influenced by the other at all*.

In this data it's clear that both variables individually are more likely to have a value close to zero, so $p(Y=0)>>p(Y=8)$ (same thing for X btw). So the fact that Y takes only value 0 when X=8 is not necessarily related to X, since even on its own Y is more likely to take value 0. In other words the question is whether $p(Y=0|X=8)$ is equal to $p(Y=0)$ or not. So the reasoning is wrong, because it doesn't take into account the individual distribution of Y, and this alone could explain why it's likely to have Y=0.

This could be calculated more formally, but my interpretation based only on this graph is that there's no evidence of dependency between X and Y.